# Protractor + ... for Cordova UWP Windows 10 Application?

Tags: cordova, automated-tests, uwp, appium

We're developing an app in Cordova, and targeting Android and iOS currently. I've got a set of tests, written in Jasmine, run by Protractor, and with Appium I test it on an Android emulator.
Works OK, the emulator is a bit slow.

We're now also targeting Windows 10. The app runs great on my Windows 10 machine. As the webview is (I guess) Edge, and there is a webdriver for Edge, I thought it would be possible to run the tests against a Windows 10 app?
But I can't find any documentation. Not sure where to start either.

When I look at the Appium example caps, I only see iOS and Android: https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/node/helpers/caps.js

So, Appium is probably not going to work. What should I use instead?